# extjs load records into form

Tags: extjs

ProductStore consist of several products and its descriptions.
product item I select from combo, description from textarea.

How can I load them back into form(combo, textarea).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume the combo is loaded from the store so the combo box has the id of the products. Put a listener on the combo box when a product is selected from the combo box get its id. Look up the id in the store and get the record. Take that record and get the data you need and populate the fields with it. Here's the basic idea you'll need to adapt this to your code.

```
var productId = combo.getValue(); //the id from the selected product in the combo box.
var rec = store.getById(productId );
//You can also use rec.get('description');
var desc = rec.data.description;
var productName= rec.data.name;
var id= rec.data.id;
//Now take these values and use them to fill in your form
textField.setValue(desc);
```